# Prevent "jump to Top" on jScrollPane

Tags: javascript, jquery, jscrollpane

I am using the jScrollPane jQuery-Plugin on a -Box which is dynamically filled with content.

My problem is that on adding new content to the front of the old content, the maintainPosition option does not work. So I wrote my own code that moves the Scrollhandle back to it's original position.
The code works fine, but calling reinitialise() after adding the new content moves the handle to the top of the container just before my code reverts it's position. This results in a short flicker of the displayed content which is very disturbing.

Does anyone know a method to prevent the scroll handler to move to the top after calling "reinitialise()"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find any integrated solution to this, so I created a workaround:
1. calculate height of prepending elements
2. prepeding new elements
3. instantly scrolling down a distance equal to the height of the new prepended elements

Answer (score 1):

Because noone has answered this question yet I've created a jsFiddle with my problem:

http://jsfiddle.net/hB4hE/1/

the calculation done on the second prepend link seems to solve the problem.
But if you run it StepByStep you see that the scrollbar is moved to top first.
Because I prepend many elements in my real environment this jumpy behavior is often visible.

So do you have an idea how to prevent it from jumping?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this setting: maintainPosition then you don't have to reposition yourself.

More information: http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/settings.html#maintainPosition

Comment: maintainPosition works if I append content to the end.
But it doesn't work if I add new content on the beginning. (as I wrote in my description above)